# If $x^2 + y^2 =36$ and $x,y<0,$ what can we conclude?

Tags: inequality

I got this question on a mock exam:

> If $x$ and $y$ are both negative numbers and $x^2 + y^2 =36,$ which of the following must be true?
>
> a) $x + y > 36$
>
> b) $x + y > 6$
>
> c) $x + y = -6\quad$ *(my original guess)*
>
> d) $x + y < -6$
>
> e) $x + y < -36\quad$ *(the "correct" answer)*

My answer:
$$x + y = -6,$$ because the square of that is $36$.

Answer according to the answer sheet:
$$x + y < -36,$$ which makes no sense to me. How does this work?

Comment: It could be a misprint for $x+y<-6$.

Comment: Both answers are wrong - you can verify this by finding counterexamples. Remember that $x^2+y^2$ is different from $(x+y)^2$.

Comment: You're on the lower left arc of a circle with radius 6. `x+y` is -6 where it either axis, but it might be longer (longest) at the 45 degree angle. Of course, if `x+y < c` than `x+y < d` for any `d > c` (transitive property)

Comment: $x+y=-6$ is a line.  At most it intersects the given circle in $2$ point.  (exactly $2$ points in this case).

Comment: The correct answer is (d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

1. > $x$ and $y$ are both negative numbers
   >
   > and $x^2 + y^2 =36,$

   Every point that satisfies these three conditions lies on the red
   quarter-circle (note that the this curve does not cut either of the
   two axes).
2. > d) $x + y < -6$

   This inequality is equivalent to $y<-x-6,$ and every point
   satisfying it lies in the blue region.

Thus, since the red curve lies within the blue region, option D must be correct.

---

> c) $x + y = -6\quad$ *(my original guess)*

This is represented by the dotted line; since the red curve does not overlap with the dotted line, option C must be wrong.

> e) $x + y < -36\quad$ *(the "correct" answer)*

This is represented by the green region; since the red curve does not overlap with the green region, option E must be wrong.

[image]

P.S. [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y7e60jcrud)'s the Desmos link for the above images.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answer should be $(d)$.

**My Solution:**

Since $x$ and $y$ are both negative, we have

\begin{align}
x+y<0,
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
xy>0.
\end{align}

Then there holds that

\begin{align}
(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2=36+2xy>36,
\end{align}

so we have

\begin{align}
x+y<-6.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

As Why Hosam Why and Bin Chen said, (d) is right. To see why geometrically, let's say that x,y > 0. Draw a circle with center at origin with radius 6. Pick an arbitrary point on circumference(for simplicity in first quadrant). The line from this point to origin is hypotenuse of a triangle with side-lengths x and y. Then you can use the triangle inequality to prove that x + y > 6. However, x and y are the lengths of the sides, so they would have to be positive. But for x,y < 0, this means that x + y  < -6.